# What type of parser is needed for this grammar?

Tags: parsing, grammar

I have a grammar that I do not know what type of parser I need in order to parse it other than I do not believe the grammar is LL(1). I am thinking I need a parser with backtracking or LL(*) of some sort. The grammar I have came up with (which may need some rewriting) is:

```
S: Rules
Rules: Rule | Rule Rules
Rule: id '=' Ids
Ids: id | Ids id
```

The language I am trying to generate looks something like this:

```
abc = def g hi jk lm
xy = aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff jjj kkk
foo = bar ha ha
```

Zero or more Rule that contain a left identifier followed by an equal sign followed by one or more identifers. The part that I think I will have a problem writing a parser for is that the grammar allows any amount of id in a Rule and that the only way to tell when a new Rule starts is when it finds id =, which would require backtracking.

Does anyone know the classification of this grammar and the best method of parsing, for a **hand written** parser?

Comment: Doesn't the last rule need to include an extra 'id' before or after the 'Ids' on the RHS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar that generates an identifier followed by an equals sign followed by a finite sequence of identifiers is *regular*. This means that strings in the language can be parsed using a DFA or regular expression. No need for fancy nondeterministic or *LL*(*) parsers.

To see that the language is regular, let *Id* = U {*a* : *a* ∈ Γ}, where Γ ⊂ Σ is the set of symbols that can occur in identifiers. The language you are trying to generate is denoted by the regular expression

- *Id*<sup>+</sup> =( *Id*<sup>+</sup>)<sup>*</sup> *Id*<sup>+</sup>

Setting Γ = {*a*, *b*, ..., *z*}, examples of strings in the language of the regular expression are:

- look = i am in a regular language
- hey = that means i can be recognized by a dfa
- cool = or even a regular expression

There is no need to parse your language using powerful parsing techniques. This is one case where parsing using regular expressions or DFA is both appropriate and optimal.

**edit:**

Call the above regular expression *R*. To parse *R*<sup>*</sup>, generate a DFA recognizing the language of *R*<sup>*</sup>. To do this, generate an NFA recognizing the language of *R*<sup>*</sup> using the algorithm obtainable from Kleene's theorem. Then convert the NFA into a DFA using the subset construction. The resultant DFA will recognize all strings in *R*<sup>*</sup>. Given a representation of the constructed DFA in your implementation language, the required actions - for instance,

- Add the last identifier parsed to the right-hand side of the current declaration statement being parsed
- Add the last declaration statement parsed to a list of parsed declarations, and use the last identifier parsed to begin parsing a new declaration statement

can be encoded into the states of the DFA. In reality, using Kleene's theorem and the subset construction is probably unnecessary for such a simple language. That is, you can probably just write a parser with the above two actions without implementing an automaton. Given a more complicated regular langauge (for instance, the lexical structure of a programming langauge), the conversion would be the best option.

Comment: Great response, however, how do I determine in a recursive descent parser when a paticular Rule is over and a new one begins, without any fancy methods. Because not only does it have to generate an identifier followed by an equals sign followed by a finite sequence of identifiers, it has to allow for a finite set of those. Im guessing it would have to be LL(3)?